# QGIS Processing Toolbox not valid

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing

I have a 64 bit windows 10 computer with ArcGis 10.2.2 Installed. I just downloaded QGIS the newest version 2.14 64 bit. it downloads but the processing toolbox throws this error

```
Couldn't load plugin 'processing' 

ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 281, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 29, in 
    from processing.tools.general import *
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 28, in 
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 40, in 
    from processing.core.GeoAlgorithm import GeoAlgorithm
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 41, in 
    from processing.core.parameters import ParameterRaster, ParameterVector, ParameterMultipleInput, ParameterTable, Parameter
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\parameters.py", line 33, in 
    from processing.tools.vector import resolveFieldIndex, features
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\vector.py", line 19, in 
    from processing.algs.qgis import postgis_utils
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\postgis_utils.py", line 28, in 
    import psycopg2
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\python27\arcgis10.2\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 50, in 
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.


Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.14.3-Essen Essen, cf2ebb8 

Python Path:
C:\Users\Ralph Zagha\.qgis2\python\plugins\GeoCoding\libs
C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/Ralph Zagha/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/Ralph Zagha/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg
c:\osgeo4~1\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.1-py2.7.egg
C:\python27\arcgis10.2\lib\site-packages
C:\python27\arcgis10.2\Script
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27
c:\progra~1\qgises~1\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
c:\progra~1\qgises~1\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
c:\progra~1\qgises~1\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg
c:\progra~1\qgises~1\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
c:\progra~1\qgises~1\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
c:\progra~1\qgises~1\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:/Users/Ralph Zagha/.qgis2//python
C:\Users\Ralph Zagha\.qgis2\python\plugins\mmqgis/forms
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISES~1\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools
```

I am not sure what to do..is it my python installation through arc that is the problem? do I have to copy my python install into the QGIS program folders?

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the entire error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably you are mixing different python libs from different python distribution:

try to clean pythonpath env var and have all your lib looked from the same env.

for osgeo4g qgis all python modules would be get from osgeo4w installation path c:\osgeo4~1\

Comment: I only have Python installed through ArcGIS..unless it is also installed for QGIS?

Comment: Python is not installed by default on WIn => most of sw that needs Python install it as boundle with the installation (to avoid administrator permissions). This happen for arc and QGIS => QGIS uses his python and arc another one... crossing them is dangerous ;)

Comment: out of curiosity why is dangerous to cross them?

Comment: was a joke from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyaLZHiJJnE